# bind mount /var with fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, bind-mount

I'm messing around with having both `/home` and `/var` on a separate partition which will be mounted in `/myhdd`.

Next, I use `mount --bind` to mount `/var` on `/myhdd/var` and `/home` on `/myhdd/home`. With this configuration I am able to successfully install Arch Linux, but as soon as I boot to the installed system `/var` and `/home` are not mount although `/myhdd` is.

Due to this issue, I can't get pacman and more important stuff working. I do get a working system if I manually mount all directories, so it looks like an fstab problem, so here it is:

```
# /dev/sda1
UUID=f192b003-abf9-4e1a-87ee-d187d64423ce   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1

# /dev/sda2
UUID=b4c5571f-ddb7-440e-b591-759e888b268d   /myhdd      ext4          rw,relatime,data=ordered  0 2

# /mnt/myhdd/home
/mnt/myhdd/home         /home       none        bind    0 0

# /mnt/myhdd/var
/mnt/myhdd/var          /var        none        bind    0 0
```

Any ideas why fstab doesn't mount my `/var` and `/home` directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem:

```
/myhdd ... /mnt/myhdd/... /mnt/myhdd/...
```

It should read either:

```
/mnt/myhddd ... /mnt/myhdd/... /mnt/myhdd/...
```

or...

```
/myhdd ... /myhdd/... /myhdd/...
```

Comment: so stupid of me...

Comment: @Rafal - it's an easy one to look past. I did three times. Sometimes just a second pair of eyes is what it takes for the bonehead stuff.

Comment: @mikeserv I know that this question is a bit dated, but could you add a "working sample" of the last alternative you wrote? Thank you in advance!